# Can I represent physical rooms in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

Given a certain AD user, I want to know what room he is in inside the company. Is it possible to map this relationship in AD?

I want to write a software that needs to know the room of the logged in user. I could of course create a separate database to hold this information, linking to the actual user, but I wondered if it wouldn't be a better approach to just add this information to Active Directory somehow and use windows authentication directly and extract this field from the user model. That way I wouldn't need to keep track of this in a separate DB and all information would be centralized in AD.

Since I'm only a developer, my knowledge of AD is very limited. But I need to know if this is at least possible and if it is a good approach to the problem, so that I can propose the change to the IT department.

The purpose of the software is to warn everyone in a certain room when anyone is on a call or needs to be focused on his task. Each user will be able to say if they need silence through this tool, and then the program needs to warn everyone on the same room about that.

Comment: I suspect the hardest problem will be capturing the room information from the user. Unless this is a fixed relationship, of course. With the right infrastructure you could use one subnet per room and derive the office from DNS.

Comment: @roaima I think this will probably be setup by the IT department itself, and not by each user. Someone would of course need to update the rooms in case someone is relocated.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Arthurs answer, which has a slight weakness in utilizing an attribute which may already fill its given function in an organisation, I would submit two alternative possibilities:

1) Using the Exchange custom attributes, if the Exchange schema has been added to the AD. The original custom attributes are described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee423541.aspx) and the newer custom attributes are mentioned and linked to [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/01/17/custom-aka-extension-attributes-in-exchange-2010-sp2-and-their-use.aspx).

2) Extending the schema with [your own custom attributes](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20319.how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-in-active-directory.aspx).

Both of these options avoid using predefined AD attributes for a different task than intended.

As both methods are explicitly supported and encouraged by Microsoft, getting IT on board should reasonably be possible. You will not find it hard to google additional documentation when building your case.

Comment: What about @TheCleaner's suggestion of using the location field? It seems to have been created to represent physical locations, so that seems appropriate to me. I've also seen some kind of "room" field in a massive xls yesterday. I'll look it up again, but it seemed to be a standard AD field. I'd like to avoid having to extend the schema or use custom Exchange attributes if there is already an attribute that was created for this purpose. Also, same thing I asked TheCleaner: do you feel this is a good approach to the problem?

Comment: Yes, @TheCleaners is definitely the best solution if it exists per user object. I wasn't aware of it's existence. I guess you should be able to verify using an ordinary ldap browser, I haven't had time to look myself yet.

Answer (score 2):

While you specify "where a user is", Microsoft does recognize the need for identify where a computer object is location wise.

There is a location field in these objects that can be formatted and used for scripting queries, assigning printers, settings in GPOs, etc.

You can find more information here on SF about it: [What is Location field in Active Directory used for?](https://serverfault.com/questions/432164/what-is-location-field-in-active-directory-used-for)

Comment: Is that field also available for users? Sorry but I'm almost completely illiterate on AD / Exchange. Also, do you think this is an elegant approach to the problem, or would you recommend something else instead of adding the info to AD directly?

Comment: @julealgon - sorry no.  The site you want to reference is here on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=VS.85).aspx - that will give you all the attributes and then you can drill into each for what classes they apply to.

Comment: What about the [room class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683924(v=vs.85).aspx)? Doesn't that exist exactly to map physical rooms? I can see it has a [`roomNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679615(v=vs.85).aspx) that the User class also has, so maybe I'm supposed to do a kind of join between them to get the room information? Thanks for the link BTW, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory specifies an "office" field under the general profile information for any given user that could be used for this. You could also create a dummy security group for each room and do it that way. This would clutter AD, but reduce processing load for the warning system (since you're not iterating so much).

Comment: This may sound a bit insane (as I said, I know almost nothing about AD and Exchange, so I'm guessing here), but what if I created dynamic distribution groups in Exchange, based on the room field? That would allow me to communicate something to the whole group, without having to create dummy entities in AD like you suggest. Would that have a similar effect?

Comment: I would wager that powershell will let you do that. Exhange exposes a LOT of cmdlets.